# c build error while linking

Tags: c

I have a problem with some program while using an external driver dll.

It compiles fine but when I try to build it I get:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall Function1(void (__fastcall*)(int))" (?Function1@@YGXP6IXH@Z@Z)
```

Header definition of the function:

```
void __stdcall                            Function1(TDeviceCallback callback);
```

Now the "unusual part"
This project is a dll that acts like a proxy between the device dll and some other application. 
Thanks to the restriction of that application being able to call c functions the proxy dll has to be build with some special options to work:

Object/Library

```
winapims.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib
```

Project options:

```
winapims.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /nologo /dll /incremental:no /pdb:"Release/test2.pdb" /machine:I386 /out:"Release/test2.fll" /implib:"Release/test2.lib"
```

It is not the first such proxy I done but it is the first time I had such a problem. Any Ideas what it could be?

EDIT:
The problem seem to be that the proxy has to be used as fastcall but the linker has problem with the conversion just in that function :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is C++'s name mangling. You need to export your C functions as follows: in your header file

```
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" MYLIB_API int fnmylib(void);
#else
MYLIB_API int fnmylib(void);
#endif
```

In your source file you define them as

```
MYLIB_API int fnmylib(void)
{ ... }
```